# CSV file import problem in ms access

Tags: ms-access

I have been trying to import a csv file to access and appending it to a table. It only imports some of the rows and stops arbitarily. All the lines in the csv file are in the same format. HAs anyone encounntred this problem? how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Are you getting any error message, or is the import creating an "import errors" table?

Comment: No it dosent give any errors or create an import errors table.
A typical line of data would be
Thu May 12 01:22:48 EST 2011,4,Urban-20kmh-500m-70s-UEnr,4,275.3443103,327.4245775,305.3507433

it randomly stops importing after a point. no errors at all

Comment: Odd. How many lines are in the file?

Comment: How are you doing the import? Via the Access user interface? In code? If the latter, what environment are you coding in?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure text data is quote-encapsulated.  You may have some text fields containing commas that can throw off the record layout and hose the entire import.